# Will a liquid-liquid emulsion and the separated emulsion have same volume?

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase, food-chemistry, colloids

Let's assume that there is no dispersed gas (bubbles). Not sure about dissolved gas; maybe you can tell me if that matters. Ordinary liquids (aqueous solution and biological oil). Surfactants are present. Same uniform temperature for both emulsion and separated emulsion.

What I'm really asking about - homogenized milk. If it has no bubbles and you centrifuge it sufficiently to separate the phases, is there a volume change? What I need is a practical answer rather than an exactly correct answer - I would say a change <0.1% is negligible. I wouldn't mind also knowing the exactly correct answer also.

Comment: The change is negligible.

Comment: I think it might in principle depend on the size of the droplets (interphase surface sum) but always negligible.